# Monitor BigQuery Performances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have BigQuery instances with various datasets for each datasets we want to monitor the usage,
like Number of Queries per datasets, Queries fired for each datasets, Number of  users accessing the datasets.

Is there any way in which we can monitor BigQuery usage?

Answer (score 0):

You can see some metrics here:
[https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards/resourceList/bigquery_dataset?project=**[YOUR_PROJECTID_GOES_HERE]*](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards/resourceList/bigquery_dataset?project=**%5BYOUR_PROJECTID_GOES_HERE%5D*)*

Some more info here as well: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring

You can also enable BigQuery audit logs, and query the audit tables to get some insights https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs.
Probably to monitor users, queries and other fine-grained monitoring you will only be able to do so using the audit logs

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the best choice here is to simply query the job metadata directly in aggregate, through the relevant INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs for details about the job views, which includes some simple query examples at the end.

The jobs views do provide a list of `referenced_tables`, and you can identify the encapsulating data from them.  You'll likely need to consider how you report on queries that reference multiple datasets, particularly if you are reporting on metrics like bytes scanned or resources utilized.